# Making a list of odd numbers from a list

Tags: haskell

I need to take odd numbers from a given list of integers to create another list.
I have written an `isOdd` function, but couldn't make the rest work.

```
isOdd :: Integer -> Bool
isOdd n = rem (abs(n)) 2 ==1 

takeOdds :: [Int] -> [Int]
...
```

Comment: Hint: use `filter`: http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:filter Haskell has already `odd` and `even` functions, so there is no reason to re-implement these.

Comment: If you want to define your own `isOdd`, use `mod` instead of `rem`; it will return `1` whether or not `n` is positive, simplifying your definition.

Comment: read https://wiki.haskell.org/How_to_work_on_lists then try to write takeOdds yourself :)

Answer (score 2):

Suppose the list is

```
x = [1,2,3,4,5,6]
```

and we can call the function `odd` using the code

```
filter odd x
```

and the result is

```
[1,3,5]
```

If you want to use your own isOdd function, you can define it like

```
isOdd x = (mod x 2) /= 0
```

and the function isOdd can be called in a similar way like

```
filter isOdd x
```

The result is the same.